# Distribution of digits across all factorials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-writing, factorial

Show that the distribution of zeroes across all digits of all *n!* for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ converges to $ \frac{1}{6} $ and hence, $\frac{5}{54}$ for all other digits *1* through *9*.

In other words, let's say we take the factorial of 1,2,3 and 4. We get the digits 1,2,2,4 and 6. In this case the probability of 2 would be $\frac{2}{5}$. We can keep doing this all the way to infinity.

I wrote a python script and checked from 0 to 10000, and all probabilities converge to 0.09259259259.. = $\frac{5}{54}$ except zero, which converges to 0.16666... = $\frac{1}{6}$.

Can you prove mathematically why this is the case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I have edited the question for further clarification.

Comment: have you thought anout ways to get a 0 ?

Comment: I wrote a python code too, but the ratios are different. 0 converges to rather large ratio.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is true

Using Stirling's approximation, the number of decimal digits in $n!$ is about $\frac1{\log_e(10)}\left(n \log_{e}(n) -n +\tfrac12 \log_{e}\left(n \right)+ \tfrac12 \log_e(2\pi)\right)$

while the number of trailing $0$s on the right hand side of $n!$ is close to $\frac n4-1$

suggesting that the proportion of digits of $n!$ which are $0$ might be estimated as being of the order of $$ \frac1{10} + \frac{9}{10} \frac{\frac n4-1}{\frac1{\log_e(10)}\left(n \log_{e}(n) -n +\tfrac12 \log_{e}\left(n \right)+ \tfrac12 \log_e(2\pi)\right)}$$ with some natural variation about this

With $n=10000$ this estimate is about $0.163$, which may help explain your empirical result of $\frac16$

But as $n$ increases further, this estimate tends to $\frac1{10}$, essentially because $n\log_e(n)$ grows faster than $\frac n4$.  For example with $n=10^{10}$ the estimate would be about $0.123$, while for $n=10^{100}$ it would be about $0.102$

Comment: Have you accounted for the fact that the first digit must necessarily not be a zero and there must necessarily be another non zero digit if the number of digits is greater than the total digits minus the number of trailing zeros, or is this insignificant? Also, is there a reason why your error is not written as on value, i.e., 2 * pi * n??

Comment: @matt We are looking at the number of decimal digits of $n!$, which is $\log_{10}(n!)$ rounded up, i.e. $\frac1{\log_e(10)}\log_e(n!)$.  Taking the logarithm of the multiplicative $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ in Stirling's approximation gives the $+\tfrac12 \log_{e}\left(n \right)+ \tfrac12 \log_e(2\pi)$ terms

Comment: @matt Your two known non-zero digits becomes insignificant for large $n$.  You are talking about the difference between $2$ (inevitably non-zero) and $1.8$ (digits non-zero with estimated rate $\frac9{10}$), which you then divide by about the number of digits of $n!$.  So perhaps you could change the $\frac n4-1$ to $\frac n4-\frac{46}{45}$ to take account of this, but it is not material in the context of the other approximations and natural variation